# EF db first and table without key

Tags: entity-framework, database-first, ef-database-first

I am trying to use Entity Framework DB first to do quick prototyping of a reporting website for a huge db. The problem is one of the tables doesn't have a key. I got an 'Error 159: EntityType has no key defined'. If I add a key on the model designer, I got 'Error 3024: Must specify mapping for all key properties'. My question is whether there is a way to workaround this WITHOUT adding a key to the table. The table is not in our control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huge table which does not have a key? It would not be possible for you or for table owner to search for anything in this table without using full table scan. Also, it is basically impossible to use UPDATE by single row without having primary key.

You really have to either create synthetic key, or ask owner to do that. As a workaround, you might be able to find some existing column (or 2-3 columns) which is unique enough that it can be used as unique key. If it is unique but does not have actual index created, that would be still not good for performance - you should create such index.